# Stack-wide Request for Comments on elections

Tags: discussion, moderation, election, moderators

Over on meta.SE (the meta that discusses Stack-wide practices and policies) there's a request that people think about and discuss how the election process works: [Help me opine about a new election system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316051/311001).

I'm dropping this "question" here really just as a pointer: many of you I know are interested in Stack-wide policies and might like to read the discussion or chime in. Many of you may never have realized there's a broader meta than this one, and this could be an interesting entry-point.

If you're curious how any proposals discussed there might impact how things run here, it's probably worth reading through a backlog of metas here on the topic of [election](/questions/tagged/election)s.

Comment: I'm closing this because the community bot is going to be regularly bumping it otherwise. It's a year old and was posted as an FYI and doesn't need the bumping.

Answer (score 0):

The use of negative voting in SE elections is not a good feature.  That the SE community embraces it is a sign of a flaw in *SE community attitudes towards people*.  That needs to be fixed, but I honestly doubt that the entrenched attitude will change.

Comment: Do you mean downvotes *during elections* or just downvoting in general? (I'm not sure I'm following you, here.)

Comment: Also, this isn't the place to opine - it's just a pointer to the actual request.

Comment: @nitsua60 During elections; edited to clarify.

Comment: @Miniman Edited to clarify.  I am not confident that listening is a feature of this request.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You might be right; it may well be pointless to post this to the RfC thread. I don't know. What I do know is that it's *definitely* pointless to post it here.

Comment: @Miniman Hmmm, meta is different.  But maybe you are right about that.

Comment: @Miniman I got roughly the response that I expected at Meta SE, though on the bright side, it attracted a reply from TuggyNE, whom I have missed "seeing" here lately.  So that was worth it, all by itself.